# Compilation warning while using codepad.org and devcpp

Tags: pointers

I am writting a program to check weather a given string is a palindrome. When I am trying to compile the code I got the below warning as

**pandridom_with_space.cpp [Error] ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]**

I know we can ignore this warning but I want to know how I can modify my code to remove this warning.

```
bool isPalindrome(const char*p,int len)
{
    if((p==NULL)||(len<1))
    return false;
    int i=0,j=len-1;
    while(p[i]!=0 && i<j)
    {
            while((i<j)&&(p[i] == " "))// <<<===== here I am getting warning.
            i++;
            while((i<j)&&(p[j] == " "))// <<<===== here I am getting warning.
            j--;
            if(p[i]!=p[j])
            return false;
            i++;
            j--;

    }
    return true;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
p[i] == " "
```

`p[i]` is a `char` (which is an integer type), and `" "` is a (`const`, since it's C++) `char` array that is converted for the comparison to a pointer to its first element.

You meant to compare it to a space character, `' '`. (Note the single quotes for a character literal, double quotes are for string literals.)